# tkinter optionmenu swapping place

Tags: python, tkinter

After googling and searching in SO, I come here.

I am making a program, but when I run it, the optionMenu widgets go to the end of the display, despite being set on the grid on the program. Here's a relevant example:

```
from tkinter import *  


root=Tk()  
root.title("Generador documentos")  


app=Frame(root)
app.grid()



sexoPat=Label(app, text ="Gender")  
sexoPat.grid(row=0,column=0)  
var1 = StringVar()  
sexoPatDrop= OptionMenu(root,var1,'Male','Female')  
sexoPatDrop.grid(row=1,column=0)  
sexoPatCheck=var1.get()


nombPat=Label(app, text ="name here")  
nombPat.grid(row=2,column=0)  
nombPatTXT=Entry(app)  
nombPatTXT.grid(row=3,column=0)
```

Comment: We need a minimal code that reproduces this behaviour to help you.

Comment: How can we possibly help with such a limited description? Please read http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: Understood, just added a code sample.

Comment: user `app` instead of `root` in `OptionMenu(root, ...)`

Answer (score 0):

In this sample code, I needed to write app instead of root in OptionMenu(root,...)

It was furas who gave me the answer.